# Joomla Buttons not showing

Tags: css, joomla

Having an issue with a joomla template.

http://se24media.net/dc3/index.php/membership/supporter/osm-sef-signup

If you hover the cursor just below the terms and conditions a button will appear but it will not show when you are not hovering.

Anyone got a fix please

many thanks

Comment: Paste you code here and show us the exact part you have problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your template css file is overriding the default button background. Go to line 286 in the the following file:

```
templates/coldzero/css/style.css
```

You should see this code

```
.btn {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Simply remove it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. i removed the line and it made no difference.  So I changed the code from background:none to background:cccccc and still no change

Any ideas?

Comment: Ekk still no joy @Lodder  that code is not on 286 but is on 571 but changing that makes no difference so stuck again :-)

Comment: but firebug tells me it is 286  confusing

Comment: Try removing it, save the file and then force refresh your browser using `CTRL` + `F5`

Comment: Ok @lodder, removed it from line 571, done F5, cleared the cache, tried it in a different browser that i never use and firbug is still telling me it is there on 286. also double checked i am updating the correct file in the correct folder

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin of some sort?

Comment: I can only see the joolma cache plugin and it is turned off. I have installed no number cache cleaner and still no go so and I am not sure cache cleaner is working. Is it worth leaving til tomorrow to see if it sorts itself out? Massive pain!

Comment: OK Update:  When I clear the cache using cache cleaner it works, until you visit the page again and then it reverts back to no button. Does this throw any light on it?

Comment: Try changing `background: none;` to `background-color: inherit;`

Comment: hi there. it was some wierd cache issue which now appears to have sorted itself out. Very odd! anyway thanks for your help in this. will mark it as closed